# Decreasing the size of a plot

Tags: pdf, plot, r, knitr

Hi there so I have this plot in knitr in R, which i want to transfer to my Latex PDF file, but it's just way too big it fills up like 3/4 of a page:

```
compPlot ( mdata$GDP, fitted( cesNewton), xlab = "Real Values",
ylab = "Fitted Values", col="red", main="Newton Method",  
cex.main=1, cex.lab=0.75, cex.axis=0.75)
```

how can I make it smaller and also center it in the middle of the page?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


<<>>=

library(micEconCES)

library(readxl)

DATA_FOR_2 <- read_excel("~/Documents/DATA FOR  2.xlsx", 
col_types = c("text", "text", "text", "text", "text", 
"numeric", "numeric","numeric", "numeric", "numeric", 
"numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", 
"numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", 
"numeric"))

mdata <- DATA_FOR_2[-c(46:62), ]

cesKmenta <- cesEst( yName = "GDP", xNames = c( "Capital", "Labour" ), 
data = mdata, method = "Kmenta", vrs = TRUE )

library( "miscTools" )

compPlot ( mdata$GDP, fitted( cesKmenta ), xlab = "Real Values",
ylab = "Fitted Values", col="red", main="Newton Method",  
cex.main=1, cex.lab=0.75, cex.axis=0.75)

@


\end{document}
```

I'm sorry I don't know how to add reproducible data, I just listed the excel sheet, which I imported

Answer (score 2):

You have to use chunk option to control the output, and read this essential page: https://yihui.name/knitr/options/

This is a MRE that answer your question

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}
\begin{figure}
\centering
<<minimal, fig=TRUE, height=12>>=
data(mtcars)
plot(mtcars[,1:2])
@
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```